# How can I see the size of a HuggingFace dataset before downloading it?

Tags: python, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I want to download a HuggingFace dataset, e.g. [`uonlp/CulturaX`](https://huggingface.co/datasets/uonlp/CulturaX):

```
from datasets import load_dataset
ds = load_dataset("uonlp/CulturaX", "en")
```

How can I see the size of a HuggingFace dataset before downloading it?